# Enter time in a column from a specific range by shuffling from time range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracleforms

Hi dear I want to put time in Table `T1` which have column `C1,C2,C3` I want to put Date in C1 the date must be enter from given date `date1` between `date2` and c2 for narration and C3 must put time by shuffling in C3 from given range mean want to add time from start `7:45` end time `8:00` and want to give for a month `Jan-2021` system can add `date` in C1 for the month and add given narration in c2 except Sunday and add time from given range by shuffling in oracle forms any idea please

Comment: Punctuation exists for a reason; use it. I read your question several times and I have **no idea** what you are saying. It has to do something with Oracle Forms, dates and times, but I got lost in "C" columns and "narrations". Hopefully, someone else will assist.

Comment: I want time to insert time in a column from range eg 7:45 to 8:00 I can do with level but it will send simultaneously i need it send it random like first it send 7:45 than 7:47 than 7:49 then 7:46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create random times, use `DBMS_RANDOM` package. For example:

Altering the session so that you'd know what `result` values represent:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.
```

Query:

```
SQL> with test (start_date) as
  2    (select to_date('01.01.2021 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  3    )
  4  select start_date + round(dbms_random.value(1, 15)) / (24 * 60) result
  5  from test
  6  connect by level <= 15;

RESULT
----------------
01.01.2021 07:49
01.01.2021 07:54
01.01.2021 07:59
01.01.2021 07:58
01.01.2021 07:56
01.01.2021 07:54
01.01.2021 07:57
01.01.2021 07:52
01.01.2021 07:54
01.01.2021 07:52
01.01.2021 07:50
01.01.2021 07:46
01.01.2021 07:53
01.01.2021 07:48
01.01.2021 07:49

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is **how**.

As I still don't understand what you're actually doing, I hope that this is enough for you to move on.

Comment: definitely I want this u are accurate but i get this error SQL*Plus internal error state 2091, context 0:0:0
Unsafe to proceed

Comment: Looks like you're using an old Oracle Client; maybe you should upgrade, if possible. Which database version do you have, and which client version do you use to connect to that database?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: This is the database (11g). And the client?

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 8.0.6.0.0 - Production

Comment: Right; quite an **old** one. I mean, 11g is old, but 8i is *ancient*. You should really upgrade. Because, as you can see in my answer, this code *works* properly. I used 11g.

Comment: :) yup i tried and it worked thanks @littlefoot u great i already accepted answer i know u r godfather of oracle and LOL ancient

Comment: dear i done in forms like this `DECLARE
 START_DATE DATE := TO_DATE('01.01.2021 07:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');
Begin
 
:a :=   START_DATE + round(dbms_random.value (1, 15))/ (24 * 60);
NEXT_RECORD;
End;` I want it to go till the other column have record how can i get this Regards in advance its work for on field as i want now just want it go through till the column b have record

Comment: You should probably **loop** through all records in a block. Exit the loop when you reach the last record; see Forms Online Help and search for `:system` variables (it is `:system.last_record` you might find useful).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228791/discussion-between-aws-and-littlefoot).